# I'm trying to use a function to read text files into arrays in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I'm trying to read two text files into separate arrays but when I debug, the numbers read from the files come out as garbage. I think it's the way I'm putting the arrays but I'm not entirely sure or it might be because the counter in the loop and the i in the array is being weird?

```
void read(ifstream &A_bank, ifstream &B_bank, string &n1, string& n2, int &i,
          int& j,  float &num, float &num1, float &total, float &total1,
          float a[], float b[])
{
    int counter = 0, counter1 = 0 ;

    getline(A_bank,n1);
    for(int i = 0; !A_bank.eof();i++)
    {
        A_bank >> a[i];
        total+=a[i];
        counter++;
    }

    getline(B_bank,n2);
    for(int j = 0; !B_bank.eof();j++)
    {
        B_bank>>b[j];
        total+=b[j];
        counter1++;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. **Always** check that you successfully read the input. 2. **Never** use `eof()` to control your loop. 3. **Always** make sure that you don't overrun the array bounds.
Fix these problems and see if there is still a problem.

Comment: Are the `a` and `b` arrays properly sized by the caller? What about using `std::vector` and its `push_back()` method to add data to the arrays (and dynamically grow them)?

Comment: It's very peculiar to me that you have a function that does the same thing twice to two arrays. Why not make a function that does a thing once to one array, and then call it twice with different arguments?

Comment: How do you invoke `read()`? How do you declare the arrays that you pass into `read()`?

Comment: Is this code from http://stackoverflow.com/q/13365877/1741542? If it is, there is a mismatch between the declaration of `read()`, it's call and the definition.

Comment: I'm pretty new to all this so if it isn't efficient then that's the reason why. Somehow only the first number in the file gets put into the array and that number gets added up to i=11 even though it should be i=10. I realized that I was calling the arrays as int even though it should have been float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your problem is wrong using of `eof()` function.
See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/eof 
eof() returns true only if last read operation failed - not when the last read operation was the last possible read operation.

Change like this both of your loops:

```
for(int j = 0; /*somehow test j here: j < MAX...*/;j++)
{
    int br;
    if (!(B_bank>>br)) {
        break;
    }
    b[j] = br;
    total+=b[j];
    counter1++;
}
```