# Struct destructor called implicitly - is my syntax wrong?

Tags: c++, class, struct

In the following code, the destructor of the struct `FileWrapper` is called by the program without me explicitly asking for it. How can I prevent this?

```
struct FileWrapper {
    std::fstream* capture_file;
    std::string filename;
    FileWrapper(std::string _filename = "./capture.dat", bool overwrite = true) {
        filename = _filename;

        std::ios_base::openmode mode = std::fstream::binary | std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::trunc;

        capture_file = new std::fstream(filename, mode);
        if (!capture_file->is_open()) {
            std::cout << "Could not open capture file.\n";
        }
    }

    void close() {
        std::cout << "closing file.\n";
        capture_file->close();
    }

    ~FileWrapper() {
        close();
    }
};

void test_file_open() {
    FileWrapper fw = FileWrapper("./fw-capture.dat");
    //Odd behaviour: fw destructor called before or during the following line
    if (!fw.capture_file->is_open()) {
        std::cout << "File Wrapper's capture file is not open.\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "File Wrapper's capture file IS open.\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Such an unnecessary use of `new`.

Comment: Desctructors are _always_ called without you asking for it.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit It is one more wrong statement. It depends on how an object was allocated and created.

Comment: @Vlad: No, it doesn't. The language specification defines the semantics of destructors, not you.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit I did not say about semantic. There are differenct posiibilities of allocating memory for an object and calling its constructor and destructor. it is you who  need to read specifications that do not say any stupidy.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: In case it helps understanding Vlad's comments: what happens if you `new` the object will the destructor be called automatically? What if you use placement-new, will it be called there? There are other more obscure cases where destructors won't be called

Comment: This code is a simplification of other code I'm using. Since the FileWrapper object is passed around, copy constructors are called on the capture_file object. I need it to be a pointer, as this constructor is private. This user found a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661257/error-c2248-stdbasic-ios-elem-traitsbasic-ios-cannot-access-private

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas While I appreciate the constructive implication that I somehow didn't "understand" his comment, that wasn't at all my point. Perhaps you did not "understand" my reponse.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: In that case I totally don't understand your response.

Answer (score 5):

Just do this

```
void test_file_open() {
    FileWrapper fw("./fw-capture.dat");
```

You are creating an extra object.

Comment: Yes, this appears to be correct. I see the copy constructor moves the capture_file pointer over to the new object.

Comment: The default copy constructor is just copying all of the members from the temporary.  So when the temporary is destroyed, its destructor closes your capture file; since the copy just keeps a pointer to the same object, it has the same affect as if you called the destructor on the copy.